# Bind DataGridTemplateColumn Visibility

Tags: data-binding, mvvm, datagrid, datagridtemplatecolumn

I am trying to bind the visibility of a column in a datagrid to a boolean DependencyProperty in the ViewModel (Set as data context of the View - UserControl in this case).
For some reason (I don't seem to understand) it just doesn't work.

After looking here I found out that the datagridtemplate (and any other template) is not part of the visual tree. So I can't bind to it.

Any simple solution to the problem (without breaking the MVVM pattern of course) ?

Comment: Is it the problem with binding like its not hitting or you are just setting it to true or false. You might need a Converter for that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Binding Visibility for DataGridColumn in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22073740/binding-visibility-for-datagridcolumn-in-wpf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution here: 
http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/

For future quenstions...