# WPF Datagrid UserControl with definable columns

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an object something like this:

```
public class Item 
{
  public string Name;
  public int Id;
  public int Quantity;
  public decimal Volume;
  public decimal Cost;
}
```

I'm wanting to create a reusable user control which would take a list of these objects and display them in a datagrid.  The trick is that I want to specify which of the properties are shown in the datagrid for each instance of the control.  Unfortunately my WPF skills are not up to the tasks and I don't want to create a specific control for each combination that I will want to use, as that feels like a lot of work for very similar code items.  Any help to pointers of how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Columns property of your datagrid to interact with the columns and hide the columns you don't want.

```
datagrid.Columns.RemoveAt(IndexOftheColumn);
```

or if you named your columns

```
datagrid.Columns.RemoveAll(x => x.Name = "column name");
```

or if it is possible that you will need to column later

```
datagrid.Columns[IndexOftheColumn].Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

It is also possible to do this with pure Xaml with bindings but since you are new to Wpf I would suggest doing it in the code behind (the .cs of your Wpf control) first.

As for selecting which columns to hide you can pass a list of names for the columns you want to remove in the constructor of the control or with a binding. There are a lot of ways to do it.

Or you could do the opposite and add columns dynamically based on your needs.

[Note that this question has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24778677/how-to-hide-datagrid-column-in-wpf-automatically-using-mvvm)