# Bind Visability of Template Column to underlying data

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I'm trying to figure out how to bind the viability of a DataGrid Template column to the observable collection that is the datacontext for the datagrid.  Note: I'm a beginner with this stuff though, so you probably have to explain like you would to a 10yr old...

I know this is is related to this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341403/wpf-datagridtemplatecolumn-visibility-binding-under-mvvm) but I still can't seem to get it to go.

I have a breakpoint in the converter but it never gets hit when data is added to the observable collection...

I hope this makes sense...
Thanks a lot

```
                    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" AlternatingRowBackground="LightBlue" ItemsSource="{Binding historyColl}" Margin="0,75,6,26" Name="historyDataGrid" FontSize="12" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="381">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Date (dd-mm)" Width="80*">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date}" Background="{Binding Converter={StaticResource TradedBackground}}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Test" Width="50" Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, 
                                Path=FrameworkElement.DataContext, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisiblityConverter}}">
                           <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Test}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Didn't you forget to define your `booleanToVisiblityConverter` in resources? Also, I would use just `Visibility="{Binding PathToVisibilityFlagInDataContext, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisiblityConverter}}"` with appropriate `PathToVisibilityFlagInDataContext`. (You seem to forget this one as well.)

Comment: I did define the converter, but did it in the window resources though... where do I put this on the C# side though?PathToVisibilityFlagInDataContext

Comment: I was basically hoping the converter would allow me to access the first row of the ObservableCollection, and then from there I could set the visibility..

Comment: Well, `PathToVisibilityFlagInDataContext` is not needed if your converter is ready to get the whole collection.

Comment: Are you sure the data context of `DataGridTemplateColumn` is what you expect? I would try `RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}`: `DataGrid` should have the data context as you expect. Did you try to check the data context with [snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/)?

Comment: Downloading snoop now, will give that a go.  I added the above relative source bit but no dice..

Comment: so I have snoop going, and have it looking at my datagrid, but I have no idea how to find that column...

Comment: Well, you can see the whole visual tree in snoop, right? You can expand the DataGrid node it and see which are the visual elements available.

Answer (score 0):

I would join the discussion below the question but I don't have enough points to do so.
I am pretty sure that `Path=FrameworkElement.DataContext` is the problem. The converter expects a boolean, but gets a DataContext instead.

I would expect a property of type `bool` within the DataContext itself to which you could bind the visibility, using the converter.

Defining the converter in window resources is just fine.